# How to display the rendered entity of entities flagged with a Search API view?

Tags: 8, entities, search

I created an index view "Search API".

I added the flags to the index.

How to display the rendered entity of entities flagged with a Search API view?

Currently only the title is displayed, I want to display the display mode "Teaser".

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to change the configuration of the **Format** section ?

Instead of "Fields" you might be able to select "Rendered entity" and then under **Settings** link, you will be able to choose a view mode like "Teaser".

[image]